# How to add two strings in an array in swift 5

Tags: swift, swift5

```
var oneArray = ["one","two","three","four"]
var secondArray = ["1","2","3","4"]
```

I want the output like

```
oneArray = ["one 1","two 2","three 3","four 4"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
let result = zip(oneArray, secondArray).map { "\($0) \($1)" }
```

**Reference**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/zip2sequence

Comment: Great! i have quick question for you. How can i manage three array?, Find index of all, so i can perform operation on it, How can i reduce ? Thanks please let me know if it not clear.

Comment: @YogeshPatel What has that got to do with the question asked here or the answer? If you want to ask a question then post a new question instead.

Comment: It works!!!! saved my day, Thank you so much @Sulthan sir, I would be able to do in conventional c++ but in swift 5 it was taking to much time